# Text::CSV_XS No such file or directory at

Tags: perl, csv, mojolicious

on my webapp (with Mojolicious), a user can upload a csv file, but i am unable to "save" it in a state variable, error:

```
[2019-03-08 11:06:07.40615] [2095] [error] ï»¿test1 ;test2;test 3;Test4;"TES;T5"
10;20;30;40;"asd;asd,asd"
11;12;13;14;15
100;95;90;85;80
: No such file or directory at /media/sf_projects/my_app/script/../lib/MyApp/Plugin/Csv.pm line 15.
```

so as we can see, the error also shows the content of my csv...

Bizarrely it works, when i load a csv file from my hdd (w/o the webapp).

code of the sub that's called by the post method:

```
  return $self->redirect_to('/') unless my $newCsv = $self->req->upload('fileToUpload')->slurp;
  $self->csv_load($newCsv);
```

"csv_load" is in a mojo plugin (the plugin of the error message Plugin/Csv.pm) which calls the following sub:

```
sub _loadCsv {
    my $controller = shift;
    my $fileLocation = shift;
    my $file = csv( in => $fileLocation, #this is line 15 of the error
                    headers => 'auto',
                    sep => ';');
    $controller->csvModel->set_array($file);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending the contents of the CSV file as an argument to the _loadCsv, which expects the *file location* to be the argument.

Comment: yes right, so do you mean i just can pass a physical file location? so i HAVE TO take the content of $newCsv, save it on my system and then load it as parameter? is there no other solution?

Comment: unfortunate not: https://mojolicious.org/perldoc/Mojolicious/Controller#param
if there's no other way, i have to take the content of $newCsv and save it as a .csv file, but i really would like to avoid this. btw thanks for your answer

Comment: The upload object (https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::Upload) may or may not save the asset to a file depending on size. You can obtain a file via the following: `my $temp = $upload->asset->to_file; my $filename = $temp->path;` (note: `$temp` may delete the temporary file once it goes out of scope) or you can write it to a specific non-temporary filename with `$upload->move_to($path)`.